# SQL Server BIDS OLE DB inputs

Tags: sql-server, bids

I have a a script component and an OLE DB destination. My script has 3 columns to return. How do I map each of these 3 columns to the OLE DB destination?

Whenever I drag a connector from the script component to the OLE DB, it makes me select exactly 1 output column. When I try again with another output column, BIDS tells me that there are no available input columns to the OLE DB destination.

Is it possible to have more than one input to an OLE DB destination?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the output columns in Script transformation .In the input and Output tab expand Output0 and specify the columns which u want .

[image: Script]